# Are hard-coded math operations performed at compile time or run time in Objective-C in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, clang, optimization

If I write a line of code for a math operation, such as:

```
x = 109.0f*768.0f/320.0f;
```

Is the result (261.6f) computed at compile time or run time?  In other words, does Xcode's optimization recognize that the result of a hard-coded math operation will always be the same, and thus can be pre-computed while compiling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is computed at compile time, at least using Xcode targetting iOS.  This function:

```
float test() {
    float x = 109.0f*768.0f/320.0f;
    return x;
}
```

compiles to these three instructions:

```
movw    r0, #52429
movt    r0, #17282
bx  lr
```

Computing the value at compile-time isn't required by the C standard.  In fact, if you set the `FENV_ACCESS` pragma, there are cases where it's forbidden from computing it at compile-time.  Turning on `FENV_ACCESS` didn't affect the generated instructions in this test case.

Comment: @rob what is the value of "Optimization Level" that you used? Is the optimization still done when "Optimization Level = None"?

Comment: It was -O0 (no optimization).